# PHP Convert float variable into digits

Tags: php

I'm  for a cryptocurrency system I need a system where I can convert integers/floats into a digit with zero's.

For example I want: 1 to be: 100000000 (8 zeros behind the comma) and so i want a float 0.1 to get 10000000 and 5.2 to be 520000000 how would I do this in PHP? I also need to . in the variable to be removed, thanks alot!

Comment: to = the in the last sentence.

Comment: best I can do is 5$... show what you have tried...somekind of effort..

Comment: How about multiplying with 100000000?

Comment: I tried to make it a string and remove the . out of it, but I don't know how to do it if the float is less than 1 or bigger than 10

Comment: @csabinho you're an life safe such a simple solution and it works great,.. I'm mind blowed hahaha thanks alot!!!

Comment: - how multiplay by million? - write 6 zeros after - tried, It did not work :)

Answer (score 1):

good day.
Hope this helps.
You can do this.

$x = 5.2

$y = $x*100000000